# Variable in JavaScript closure

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, closures

I have a loop that that subscribes to different PubNub channels (dont worry about the PubNub specifics, problem seems to be scope/closures). When I receive a message, I want to resolve a promise.

The problem is indicated with comments in code below. Basically, outside the pubnub subscribe, the counter `i` gives the expected value, however inside the subscribe callback, its not. Why is this the case? How do I fix it?

```
_.times(3, function(i) {
    console.log('subscribe'+i); // here counter is working fine
    pubnub.subscribe({
        channel_group: 'usersu' + (i + 1) + ':1',
        callback: function(msg) {
            console.log('recv:', msg, message, msg == message, i); // here its not! i is always 0
            if (msg == message) {
                console.log('resolve');
                deferreds[i].resolve();
            }
        },
        error: function(err) {
            deferreds[i].reject(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: callback: function({"msg":msg, "i": i}) { ... could help you?

Comment: @InvernoMuto You don't get to choose which parameters are passed to the callback you provide.

Comment: Wait...your code gets the wrong value for `i`? It's *already* in a context where `i` shouldn't be changing... [It works here](http://jsfiddle.net/t7952dpo/). Can you create an [MCVE](/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem? It should be working (at least as far as `i` is concerned).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, my bad

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes I am not sure why too ... the console.logs tell me I have the right `i` before subscribe, but in the subscribe callback, I got a wrong `i` ...

Comment: @JiewMeng: That simply won't happen with the code you've posted above. Something *else* is going on. Creating an [MCVE](/help/mcve) will either 1) Help you figure out what it is, or 2) Give you something you can post a question about. We can't answer the question as it is now, since the code in the question won't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping you already solved this issue.

I modified your code to run it locally on a browser. I declared a new function subscribe (since we don't know what pub nub subscribe). This code works perfectly and the corresponding "i" value is printed.

I think you need to provide a bit more context and the environment for the community to debug further.

```js
function subscribe(obj) {
  console.log(obj.channel_group);
  obj.callback("hello");
  obj.error("error5");
}

_.times(3, function(i) {
  console.log('subscribe' + i); // here counter is working fine
  subscribe({
    channel_group: 'usersu' + (i + 1) + ':1',
    callback: function(msg) {
      console.log('recv:', msg, "hello", "hello"==msg, i); // here its not! i is always 0
      if (msg == "hello") {
        console.log('resolve');
        console.log(i);
        //deferreds[i].resolve();
      }
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log(i + ": " + err);
      //deferreds[i].reject(err);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js"></script>
```